# Running applications through sdcard

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have put my compiled application in /data/data folder of my android. And I can run it through terminal emulator. How to add that application to "Application list". So, that I can see it as an icon.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "run" the app to install it. Use a program like [Astro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro&feature=search_result) to browse to it and click the app to install it. This will place the icon in your application list.

**Update**

If you want to install via the terminal emulator, you have to do the following (note: you need to be root on your phone to do this).

1. Place the .apk on the root of your SD card (for simplicity)
2. Type "su"
3. cd into the destination of your .apk (in this case it will be cd /sdcard)
4. Use "install "name of .apk" /"destination"/"name of .apk"

More information here: http://bit.ly/cpnocZ

Comment: do you know why this does not happen when I run the application through terminal emulator. If I can do this without Astro then it would be better.

Comment: @agent.smith - I updated with how to do the install from the terminal emulator. You'll need to be root in order to do this method, however. I don't know of another method. Astro works well - any particular reason you want to do it only from the TE?

Comment: Hey, thanks. I am running android's x86 port. It is generally painful to use stuff meant for android-x86. su does not work with terminal emulator. But if I do Alt-F1 then it goes into root mode and it starts working. :)